# Connection Changed broadcast doesn't work when mobile data is enabled in Marshmallow

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, data-connections

I have registered `ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` to get broadcast when `WIFI is connected`. It doesn't work when my `mobile data is enabled` and connected WIFI has no internet connection.

I have created a `hotspot` in another mobile device which has no internet connection. In `my device (Android 6.1)` `mobile data` is enabled. When I try to connect to the `hotspot`, broadcast doesn't trigger. It works every time when `mobile data is disable`.

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
registerReceiver(networkStateReceiver, intentFilter);

private BroadcastReceiver networkStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intentData)
        {
            String action = intentData.getAction();
            Log.e("action",action);
            if (action.equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)){
                // trigger once (when register).
            }
        }
}
```